# Obtener todas las url usando googleapis y blogger

Tags: php, curl, google-api, blogger

Hola busco alguna manera de obtener todas las **url** de las entradas de un blogs de **blogger** e usado esta manera

https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v2/blogs/49788022/posts?callback=handleResponse&prettyPrint=true&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&fields=items(url)

Usando la Api de google me da el siguiente resultado:

```
// API callback
handleResponse({
 "items": [
  {
   "url": "http://chicassexyhot.sigue.la/2018/01/baby-got-cakes.html"
  },
  {
   "url": "http://chicassexyhot.sigue.la/2018/01/amber-lynn-jr-carrington-holly-body-in.html"
  },
  {
   "url": "http://chicassexyhot.sigue.la/2018/01/episode-11-beauty-of-dawn-part-1.html"
  },
  {
   "url": "http://chicassexyhot.sigue.la/2017/12/cici-rodes-interracial-creampie-gangbang.html"
  },
  {
   "url": "http://chicassexyhot.sigue.la/2017/12/adorable-jovencita.html"
  },
  {
   "url": "http://chicassexyhot.sigue.la/2017/12/exotic-baby-shows-bigtits-on-webcam.html"
  },
  {
   "url": "http://chicassexyhot.sigue.la/2017/12/ass-traffic-model-beautys-bodacious.html"
  },
  {
   "url": "http://chicassexyhot.sigue.la/2017/12/amateur-pregnant-teen-plays-with-her.html"
  },
  {
   "url": "http://chicassexyhot.sigue.la/2017/12/hard-body-blond-milf.html"
  },
  {
   "url": "http://chicassexyhot.sigue.la/2017/12/hungarian-sexy-blond-bambi-on-erotic.html"
  }
 ]
}
);
```

Como pueden ver solo me da un numero reducido de las entradas y lo que necesito es obtener el total de las url de las entradas que son un total de 350 .

espero me puedan dar alguna idea de como lograr la paginacion .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bien luego de buscar información sobre la APi de blogger Logre encontrar la manera y hoy se las comparto :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v2/blogs/**AQUI EL IDE DEL BLOGS**/posts?callback=handleResponse&prettyPrint=true&maxResults=300&key=**SU API KEY**&fields=kind,items(url)
```

Y esto les dará el resultado máximo de 300 url. Mas de 300 no es posible .

Saludes